# NLog - Cleaning up log files that have dynamic file names

Tags: c#, nlog

I have an application that will be receiving messages through a queuing system, I would like to log each message to its own file, with the file name being the message id.  I figured out how to accomplish this using the event-context within the filename.

Though the maxArchiveFiles setting does not have any affect, probably because I'm not archiving any files.  Using this configuration is there any way I can leverage NLog to limit the number of files either by date or count?

```
 <target name="testfile" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${message}"
            fileName="c:\SupportLogs\${event-context:item=MessageId}.txt"
            maxArchiveFiles="50"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="iso-8859-2" />


    NLog.Logger oLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Test");
    NLog.LogEventInfo oEvent = new NLog.LogEventInfo(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, "", "My Message");
    oEvent.Properties["MessageId"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    oLogger.Log(oEvent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the NLog at the moment. You have to clean up the log files yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it doesn't seem to work, I added the following to the config archiveFileName="c:\SupportLogs\${event-context:item=MessageId}.txt" archiveEvery="Minute"

Comment: Yeah, sorry event-context aren't available at during archiving, well it will always be empty. I'm changing my answer