# Cleanup the folder of logs with custom file names

Tags: c#, nlog

I log some stuff with `LogEventInfo`, because I'm adding a variable property called `Action` to each log. In my target the `layout` is simple, `layout="${message}"`, but `fileName` is complex, `fileName="C:\log\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss} ${event-properties:item=Action}.log"`.

But I still want to restrict the space taken with all these log files. It doesn't matter if it's by size, or date, or number of files. How do I archive log files with such custom file name?

There is an answer [from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16741044/395718) stating that this is not possible, but I'm hoping that that answer is now incorrect, even if it was correct back then.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501773/how-to-set-nlog-max-file-size/50501933)?

Comment: @Pavel I did try `archiveAboveSize="1"`. The file is not archived if a log *would* exceed the size, but rather if the size is already exceeded on the *next* log. This messes up the file names. But maybe I'm doing it wrong, and if you have a solution please post it.

Comment: _Size in bytes above which log files will be automatically archived_ I don't think that log file with 1 byte size make sense. Try to follow an official sample, set the size to 10240 (10 kB). Refer to options [description](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archival-options)

Comment: @Pavel, this will set the size of one file. How does this help me? I don't need to set the size of one file. In fact one file in my case has only one message, because file name has current date and time up to a minute, so size of one file does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end my solution was to delete all *.log files from the folder, except the N newest ones, before I write a new log. These logs are not of the regular kind, so special cleanup for special logging case is fine.